# Linq expression for where condition on entity child

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, linq-expressions

Hello,

how can I build following statement via linq expressions in order to be translated into sql?

```cs
builder.Where(e => e.SomeChild.Name.ToLower() == "something");
```

The `builder` is a DbContext. When I call it directly, it's interpreted correctly like this

```cs
select ... from someTable 
inner join childTable on ... 
where LOWER(childTable.Name) = @someParam
```

so I build the where condition this way:

```cs
private readonly Expression<Func<TEntity, TProperty>> _property;

private Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> insensitiveEqualityPredicate(string formula)
        {
            var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TEntity));
            var property = (PropertyInfo)((MemberExpression)_property.Body).Member;
            var propertyParameter = Expression.Parameter(property.DeclaringType);
            var lowerExpression = Expression.Call(
                    Expression.Invoke(_property, propertyParameter),
                    typeof(string).GetMethods().Where(m => m.Name == "ToLower" && m.GetParameters().ToList().Count == 0).FirstOrDefault()
                    );
            return Expression.Lambda<Func<TEntity, bool>>(
                Expression.Equal(
                    lowerExpression,
                    Expression.Constant(formula.ToLower(), typeof(string))
                ),
                parameter
            );
        }
```

---

It works like charm:

```cs
_property = e => e.Name;
...
builder.Where(insensitiveEqualityPredicate("whatever"));
```

But does not work for conditions on children:

```cs
_property = e => e.SomeChild.Name;
...
builder.Where(insensitiveEqualityPredicate("whatever"));
```

Because:

```cs
The LINQ expression 'Param_0.Name.Equal("whatever")' could not be translated and will be evaluated locally.
```

What is the correct approach?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: `_property` holds expression like `e => e.Name` or `e => e.SomeChilld.Name`, correct?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. I'll edit that for clarity

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By my understanding, you have a field `_property` of type `Expression<Func<TEntity, TProperty>>` (in this particular case it's actually `Expression<Func<TEntity, string>>`) which is initialized with lambda expression like `e => e.Name`, `e => e.SomeChild.Name` etc.

In order to build the desired predicate you could reuse the `_property` expression parameter and use the [`Body`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.lambdaexpression.body(v=vs.110).aspx) property as base for the new expression:

```
private readonly Expression<Func<TEntity, TProperty>> _property;

private Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> insensitiveEqualityPredicate(string formula)
{
    return Expression.Lambda<Func<TEntity, bool>>(
        Expression.Equal(
            Expression.Call(_property.Body, "ToLower", Type.EmptyTypes),
            Expression.Constant(formula.ToLower(), typeof(string))
        ),
        _property.Parameters
    );
}
```